# Share a function among two apex classes

Tags: apex, design-patterns

I have two class that both have this function

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String talkToAuthorizeDotNet(String body){
    return AuthorizeDotNetUtility.makeCallout(body);
}
```

Is there a better way to share the `AuthorizeDotNetUtility.makeCallout()` among my two classes? `AuthorizeDotNetUtility.makeCallout()` is about 20 lines of code, so I didn't want to repeat myself, but I still ended up repeating myself..

Ideally it would be nice to share `AuthorizeDotNetUtility.makeCallout()` among my two classes without having to create `talkToAuthorizeDotNet()` in them.

Comment: If you able to create single entry point for calling then it will solve your purpose

Comment: In it's current form, you seem to already share the code in your utility class. However because the methods are aura enabled, thus you are most likely using two different controllers on your LC. As long as you are able to refactor the LCs to use a single controller and a single method `talkToAuthorizeDotNet()`, then that's where you can reduce the redundancy of writing same methods across different classes.

Comment: If the two @AuraEnabled methods are in classes that have different responsibilities, then leaving them separate makes sense and your approach of composing in the authorisation is a good way to go. (Inheritance is way less popular than it once was.)